# disable works in every browser but IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, riot.js

On a certain condition a button has to be disabled, if that condition is true and the button is disabled, the style that has to be applied is so in every browser including IE, on mouse over a prohibitory sign pops up, but in IE a click is still registered and executed. I could use a condition surrounding the event, so if the disable condition is true, that the code isn't executed, this works but isn't allowed because of architectural rules. The disable property is set, but still onclick is triggered.

I don't think my code will be of any value because my description of the problem is a global issue on every button in the application, so there has to be a IE specific solution which can be applied to the custom button control to set the property, but IE says that property disabled = true.

Comment: Please. You need to show code. Disabled means different things to different people. Recreate a similar problem in jsfiddle or jsbin and come back.

Comment: `<mdt-button>
    <style scoped>
        :scope[disabled],
        :scope button[disabled] {
        }
    </style>
    <button type="{ type }" disabled="{disabled:disabled}"</button>
    <script>
        this.on('update', function() {
            this.faceIcon = this.opts['face-icon'];
            this.disabled = this.opts.__disabled;
            this.type = this.opts.type ? this.opts.type: 'button';
        });
    </script>
</mdt-button>` because it's so much code to describe the control, I narrowed it down

Comment: http://riotjs.com/faq/#why-ie8-is-not-supported

Are you talking about IE8? Because it looks like your chosen framework says "no".

Comment: IE11, but the website also has to support version 9 and 10 because of HTML5

Comment: This by the way is Riot.js code it is not what you could consider "HTML5".  There is no HTML element called "mdt-button" for example. I have to apologize and say I'm out. You did write riot.js and I didn't realise that that was a full React like framework.

It looks pretty good all the same
http://riotjs.com/api/

Comment: No but the lack of html5 support in older browsers was the reason of the architect not to develop for support before IE9, but that's not my call to take into questioning why and why not. But in what way would the api documentation help me to disable the event from happening

Answer (score 0):

I had lots of problems with IE aswell so far, and they don't seem to have an end anytime soon. :)

Disabled is a property I always have to play around a lot to make it work how I want it.

Since you didn't provide any code, just try the following for disabling:

```
$("#yourid").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

OR

```
$("#yourid").attr("disabled", true);
```

And this for enabling:

```
$("#yourid").attr("disabled", false);
```

OR

```
$("#yourid").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: onclick still executed

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess as I'm not familar with  Riot.js but the code you have there is malformed. the button tag wasn't closed. Browsers handle malformed code differently so you should check that.

```
<mdt-button>
  <style scoped>
    :scope[disabled],
    :scope button[disabled] {}
  </style>
  <button type="{ type }" disabled="{disabled:disabled}"> </button>
  <script>
    this.on('update', function() {
      this.faceIcon = this.opts['face-icon'];
      this.disabled = this.opts.__disabled;
      this.type = this.opts.type ? this.opts.type : 'button';
    });
  </script>
</mdt-button>
```

Comment: button tag is close, there is </button> I have to limit the code in comments because limited amount of characters allowed

Comment: Please edit your question and add code.

This is what you have pasted, it is malformed please confirm it is not like that in the real code; it is missing '>' after the attributes.

<button type="{ type }" disabled="{disabled:disabled}"</button>

Comment: as far as I see their aren't any closing tags missing `<mdt-button>
    <style scoped>
    </style>
    <button type="{ type }" disabled="{disabled:disabled}" name="{ name }" clickEvent="{ clickEvent }">{ label }</button>
    <mdt-icon class="icon" if="{faceIcon}" face="{faceIcon}"/>
    <script>
    </script>
</mdt-button>`

Comment: There is a disabled button in the default app. Does it work with IE11. Also its syntax for the disabled button is like this: 

<button disabled={ !text }>
So just boolean in the curly brackets.
http://riotjs.com/examples/plunker/?app=todo-app